# WebSocketSharp C# StreamReader?

Tags: c#, websocket, streamreader, binance

I have a problem i would like to know how to read the WebSocket response with StreamReader ?

```
        //WebSocket
        WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/api/v3/userDataStream");
        ws.Connect();
```

it's to do this: https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/user-data-stream.md#create-a-listenkey

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some example to receive data from a `WebSocket` with a `StreamReader`.

```
 public async Task<string> Receive()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        WebSocketReceiveResult result = await client.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);//ToDo built in CancellationToken

        if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
        {
            return "abort";
        }

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Write(buffer,0, result.Count);
            while(!result.EndOfMessage)
            {
                result = await client.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);//ToDo built in CancellationToken
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, result.Count);
            }

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string message = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the link to the website for this code samples: https://mycsharp.de/forum/threads/122437/websocket-client-beispiel

There is another example to read and write from a websocket:
https://thecodegarden.net/websocket-client-dotnet

I hope this can help you to solve your problem.